# NoClassDefFoundError error with JDBCPool in vertx 4.3.2

Tags: jdbc, vert.x, vertx4

I am getting error with new JDBCClient API.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/agroal/api/configuration/supplier/AgroalDataSourceConfigurationSupplier
```

Created project from starter, included jdbc-client and H2 database API.

```
JDBCPool pool = JDBCPool.pool(
      vertx,
      // configure the connection
      new JDBCConnectOptions()
        // H2 connection string
        .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:~/test")
        // username
        .setUser("sa")
        // password
        .setPassword(""),
      // configure the pool
      new PoolOptions()
        .setMaxSize(16)
    );
```

while retrieving connection getting NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the vert.x client requires a pool, all pool implementations are marked as optional dependencies and your build tool does not pull it to your project. Which means you need to explicitly add it; otherwise you will see that error. For this case, you will need:

```
io.agroal:agroal-api1.16
io.agroal:agroal-pool:1.16
```

For the future, the plan is to rely just on a `javax.sql.DataSource` and keep the pool agnostic. Most pools do implement this interface, so users are free to choose to use a pool or not.

Comment: I see some intermittent issues with queries, some times all queries got executed successfully and sometime few get executed.